# Gradient using autograd function error python

Tags: python, function, gradient, autograd

I am trying to compute the gradient of some function using autograd but fails and shows the below error

```
from autograd import grad
def f(a): 
   return a[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[1]) + a[2]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[3])

a=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0] 
gr = grad(f,0)
print(gr(a))
```

File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\auto.py", line 23, in f
    return a[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[1]) + a[2]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[3])

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type ArrayBox which has no callable sin method

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I think this a problem with autograd. You have to import numpy from autograd! Add at the beginning : import autograd.numpy as np

```
from autograd import grad
import autograd.numpy as np ; <-----------

def f(a): 
   return a[0]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[1]) + a[2]*np.sin(2*np.pi*a[3])

a=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0] 
gr = grad(f,0)
print(gr(a))
```